# Ruby on rails admin actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Rails 4 and I'm looking to build in some basic admin functionality such as creating and viewing users. I can think of a few ways to do it manually, (such as creating a new controller or adding filters) but I'm pretty sure there's a "Rails Way" to do this easily. I've been digging through the docs and I see references to "built in authentication" that support my hunch, but I can't find the actual documentation.

For example, in CakePHP you can just prefix actions with `admin_` and `/admin/controller/action` will work automatically. Is there a similar convention for Rails? If so, where can I find it?

**Update:**
As I continue to research this, I start to get the impression that admin authorization in Rails is commonly not handled by the Rails core, but rather in a gem like [cancan](http://rubydoc.info/gems/cancan/1.6.10/frames). Perhaps this is why I was striking out by searching the Rails docs.

**Update2:**
This question wasn't intended to be a round-up of authorization gems, but since it appears gems are the typical way to handle even basic admin authorization, I'd like to find the simplest, most basic (and hopefully universal) option. A couple options have been proposed below which come bundled with default dashboard views and elaborate configurations. I don't need all that. Just a simple, reliable strategy for dividing users into admins and non-admins with different scopes of allowed actions.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces

Comment: There is normally a Gem for it, check ruby toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Check out the awesome rails_admin gem. It automatically generates just about everything you could need. Very handy and awesome project. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Authentication is handled via the devise gem and authorization via cancan.

It's no replacement for custom admin functionality if you have very specific requirements, but it's great for general admin tasks you described.